Can I change search query language with a keyboard shortcut in duckduckgo (through firefox)?
I am an happy user of duckduckgo to search the web. For that, I am using duckduckgo as my default search engine in Mozilla Firefox. With my keyboard, I type ctrl + l to move the focus in the URL bar, and then I type what I want to search for here and reach enter. For exemple, searching for "test" I get the following at the top of the page my browser is showing :

In this context, I use very often the "France" checkbox (I am in France with an English system) to switch between searches in French and English web sites.
What I am asking here is for a way to have a keyboard shortcut to toggle this checkbox ? (I asked Lama through the new Beta AI feature of duckduckgo that answered used ctrl + shift + l but this has no effect and looking into duckduckgo documentation I can't see any shortcut to change search language)
